# Integration problem 1

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

what is
$I(2n) =\int \tan^{2n}x\mathrm{d}x$

Thanks

Comment: Hint: $\tan^{2n}x=\tan^{2n-2}x\,\tan^2x$.

Answer (score 2):

This does not require integration by parts. As user170231 points out $\tan^{2n}x=\tan^{2n-2}x\tan^2x$. Now, use the identity $\tan^2x=\sec^2x-1$ to arrive at
\begin{align*}
\int\tan^{2n}xdx&=\int\tan^{2n-2}x(\sec^2x-1)xdx\\
&=\int\tan^{2n-2}x\sec^2xdx-\int\tan^{2n-2}xdx\\
&=\frac{1}{2n-1}\tan^{2n-1}x-\int\tan^{2n-2}xdx
\end{align*}

**Added:** To solve the specific problem in your comment, use
$$I(2n-2)=\frac{1}{2n-1}\tan^{2n-1}x-I(2n).$$
Starting with $n=-1$ and applying this twice yields
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{1}{\tan^4x}dx&=-\frac{1}{3\tan^3x}+\int\frac{1}{\tan^2x}dx\\
&=-\frac{1}{3\tan^3x}-\frac{1}{\tan x}+\int dx\\
&=-\frac{1}{3\tan^3x}-\frac{1}{\tan x}+x
\end{align*}

Comment: The next part is  Hence show that the integral between π/4 and π/2 of 1/tan^4(x)dx=π/4−2/3. I've done this in a similar way to the first part but don't know where the 'hence show' part comes in, so I was thinking there might be an alternate way for the first part which requires integration by parts.

Answer (score 1):

David Hill's answer is the better one, but if you absolutely must use integration by parts somewhere, here's one way:

\begin{align*}
I(2n) &= \int \tan^{2n} x ~dx \\
&= \int \tan^{2n-2} x (\sec^2 x - 1) ~dx \\
&= \int \underbrace{\tan^{2n-2} x}_{u} ~\underbrace{\sec^2 x ~dx}_{dv} - I(2n-2) \tag{$\alpha$}\\
&= \left(\tan^{2n-1} x - \int (2n-2) \tan^{2n-3} x \tan x \sec^2 x ~dx \right) - I(2n-2)\\
\Rightarrow I(2n)&\overset{(a)}{=} \tan^{2n-1} x - (2n-2) \left(I(2n) + I(2n-2) \right) - I(2n-2)\\
\Rightarrow I(2n) &= \frac{1}{2n - 1} \left( \tan^{2n-1} x - (2n -1 ) I(2n-2) \right)
\end{align*}

Where in step $(a)$ I'm using the relation developed in equation $(\alpha)$

Answer (score 1):

You may also replace $x$ with $\arctan t$ and check that:

$$ J(2n)=\int \frac{t^{2n}}{t^2+1}\,dt = \int\frac{1}{t^2+1}\,dt + \int\left(t^{2n-2}-t^{2n-4}+\ldots-(-1)^n\right)\,dt $$
from which:
$$ J(2n) = \frac{t^{2n-1}}{2n-1}-J(2n-2).$$